# Как добавить пользовательский маркер на карту с использованием Python Folium?

Tags: python, folium

Я делаю интерактивную карту на python folium и хочу сделать свой маркер(иконку) на карте. Список встроенных маркеров в folium я не смог найти. В последующем я хочу добавить несколько маркеров не стандартного вида и сделать чтоб они двигались по карте(координаты для них передаются). Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать нестандартные маркеры и достаточно ли функционала у folium для передвижения этих маркеров по заданным координатам?

Метки подобные этим.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ создания собственных маркеров.

```
    icon_size = (14, 14)

for feature in stations['features']:
    lon, lat = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    icon_url = feature['properties']['icon']
    popup = feature['properties']['popupcontent']
    
    icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_url,
                                      icon_size=(14, 14))
    
    marker = folium.map.Marker([lat, lon], icon=icon,
                               popup=folium.map.Popup(popup))
    mapa.add_children(marker)
```